# Time-based workflow queue limit

Tags: limits, time-dependent-workflow

Does anyone know if there's a limit to the number of pending actions in the time-based workflow queue?  Given that it has filtering options in the monitor I assume it's expecting more than just a handful, but I haven't been able to track down a specific limit.  Is 25,000 too many?  What about 100,000?

I'd appreciate any feedback, but especially links to official (or semi-official) documentation of said limits.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tested this or found a solid answer? I am just about to need the same information:)

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is any such limit, nothing that I came across. Lets consider I created 10 Million accounts using dataloader and have a workflow rule with time trigger like 10 days after created date, the queue may show 10 million pending actions if I search by this workflow name. The only thing you need to take care is the hourly limit of execution.

Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00 PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and 6:00 PM.

Comment: There's a limit, it maybe negligibly high and undocumented but there is a theoretical limit. The question is, what happens when that limit is hit?

Answer (score 2):

Per the help docs

> Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can
>   execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its
>   Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time
>   triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition
>   organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00
>   PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00
>   PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and
>   6:00 PM.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I saw that per-hour limit, but what I'm more interested in is the "total" pending actions.

Comment: I do not believe there is a total

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_approvals_workflows.htm&language=en_US

Each workflow rule can have:

```
10 time triggers
40 immediate actions
40 time-dependent actions per time trigger
```

The immediate actions and each time trigger can have:

```
10 email alerts
10 tasks
10 field updates
10 outbound messages
10 flow triggers1
```

Workflow Time Triggers Per Hour 
prof-250    enterprise-500  dev-50  unlimited-1,000

Comment: Good information but doesn't answer the question. There has to be an upper limit on how many can be stored in the queue, maybe it's so large that it doesn't need to be worried about, never the less it would be nice to know definitively

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this per-hour limit can be increased by logging a case w SFDC